# Why Is Null Ignored In Query Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, null

I have a table with similar structure to the below, and a field has a `NULL` value in it.  When I query the table this record is not returned, it is omitted.  How should the query be altered so that this record is returned?

```
Declare @Fiesty Table
(  
  numberfour varchar(100)
  ,valid varchar(20)
)

Insert Into @Fiesty (numberfour, valid) Values
('1ACRELBS', NULL), ('4ACRELBS', 'Green'), ('17ACRELBS', 'White')

Select * FROM @Fiesty WHERE valid NOT IN ('Green', 'Blue', 'White')
```

My expected returned result would be where `numberfour = 1ACRELBS`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SQL uses [ternary (three-valued) logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) and comparisons with `NULL` are tricky, counter intuitive. Regarding the condition:

```
WHERE valid NOT IN ('Green', 'Blue', 'White')
```

it expands to:

```
WHERE valid <> 'Green' AND valid <> 'Blue' AND valid <> 'White'
```

When `valid` is `NULL`, all these 3 sub-conditions evaluate to `UNKNOWN` (neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`). The whole condition evaluates to `UNKNOWN` as well and thus the row rejected (`WHERE` keeps only the rows that the condition evaluates to `TRUE`).

When comparing nulls, you can think this way. I don't know the exact value of `valid` so I can't be sure if it's going to be different to `'Green'` or not. It might be and it might be not. The result is `UNKNOWN`.

---

If the intention is to get in the result the rows where `valid IS NULL`, you can use either:

```
SELECT * FROM @Fiesty 
WHERE valid IS NULL
   OR valid NOT IN ('Green', 'Blue', 'White') ;
```

or `EXISTS / EXCEPT` (or `NOT EXISTS / INTERSECT`):

```
SELECT f.* FROM @Fiesty AS f 
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT f.valid 
      EXCEPT 
        SELECT v.valid 
        FROM
            ( VALUES ('Green'), ('Blue'), ('White') )
            AS v (valid)
      ) ;
```

There is also a `NOT EXISTS` way which is my opinion to be preferred to `NOT IN`, especially because the behaviour regarding nulls is more intuitive. (Notice also the similarity with the `INTERSECT` version):

```
SELECT f.* FROM Fiesty AS f
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM
            ( VALUES ('Green'), ('Blue'), ('White') )
            AS v (valid)
        WHERE v.valid = f.valid
      ) ;
```

Test at **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=48383e29a28a95c922fc8dc0a16067a3)**.

Comment: There's also the `LEFT JOIN` + `IS NULL` method (where, by the way, you can avoid `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ...` and go just `VALUES ...`).

Comment: Another possibility (for 2022+ rather than 2008 as tagged) is `Select * FROM @Fiesty WHERE valid IS DISTINCT FROM ALL (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('Green'),('Blue'),('White')) V(cols))`